# Duplicate Data over One-to-Many self relation (Tsql)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Sorry if the title is poorly descriptive, but I can't do better right now =(

So, I have this master-detail scheme, with the detail being a tree structure (one to many self relation) with n levels (on SQLServer 2005)

I need to copy a detail structure from one master to the another using a stored procedure, by passing the source master id and the target master id as parameters (the target is new, so it doesn't has details).

I'm having troubles, and asking for your kind help in finding a way to keep track of parent id's and inserting the children without using cursors or nasty things like that...

[image: table model for the problem]

This is a sample model, of course, and what I'm trying to do is to copy the detail structure from one master to other. In fact, I'm creating a new master using an existing one as template.

Comment: So your detail table has details of its own in the same table? Something like:

MasterID
DetailID
ParentDetailID

Where ParentDetailID refers back to a row in the Details table?

Comment: yes, detail.ParentDetailID is FK for detail.DetailID and detail.MasterID is FK for master.MasterID

Comment: So is detail.MasterID populated for ALL detail rows, or just for the "root" node of the tree of details?

Comment: Ah - I see now. I thought you were wanting to *move* detail rows from one master to another, and couldn't understand what the problem was. Certainly copying is a harder problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem, this might be what you want:

```
INSERT dbo.Master VALUES (@NewMaster_ID, @NewDescription)

INSERT dbo.Detail (parent_id, master_id, [name])
SELECT detail_ID, @NewMaster_ID, [name]
FROM dbo.Detail 
WHERE master_id = @OldMaster_ID

UPDATE NewChild
SET parent_id = NewParent.detail_id
FROM dbo.Detail NewChild
JOIN dbo.Detail OldChild
ON NewChild.parent_id = OldChild.detail_id
JOIN dbo.Detail NewParent
ON NewParent.parent_id = OldChild.parent_ID
WHERE NewChild.master_id = @NewMaster_ID
AND   NewParent.master_id = @NewMaster_ID
AND   OldChild.master_id = @OldMaster_ID
```

The trick is to use the old `detail_id` as the new `parent_id` in the initial insert.  Then join back to the old set of rows using this relationship, and update the new `parent_id` values.

I assumed that `detail_id` is an IDENTITY value.  If you assign them yourself, you'll need to provide details, but there's a similar solution.

Comment: wow, this worth a try, thanks!, I'll be back with results by tomorrow!

Comment: It did!!, sorry for the delay. Thanks you very very much.

Comment: Glad to help.  It was an interesting puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to provide create table and insert into statements for little sample data.
and expected results based on this sample data.